# Call the roll in the classroom?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, word-request

What do you call when the teacher calls out the students' names in the classroom in order to see who's present or absent? Are these options correct? Which is the preferred form in AmE?

Call the roll - AmE

Make the roll call - AmE

Take attendance - AmE

Call the register - BrE

Comment: Where did you get these options from?

Comment: @user3169 from this website https://www.englishexperts.com.br/forum/como-dizer-fazer-a-chamada-da-classe-em-ingles-t28963.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[take attendance](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/take%20attendance)*** is mainly used in AmE:

> - make a record of who is present. *The teacher takes attendance every day.*

(M-W)

***[To call the roll](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/To+call+the+roll)*** is used both in  AmE and BrE:

> - to call off or recite a list or roll of names of persons belonging to an organization, in order to ascertain who are present or to obtain responses from those present.

Also ***[roll call](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/roll_call):***

> - the  process of calling out a list of names to establish who is present.

***[call/take the register](http://webster)*** is mainly BrE:

> - to read out an official list of names. * After the students were seated, the teacher called/took the register.*

(M-W)/