# What is the term for activity when a teacher is account for students presence in his class?

Tags: word-request

What is the term for activity when a teacher is account for students presence in his class?

In my native language, this is called "Absency" (absensi). I believe this was a term (incorrectly) absorbed from English. I know that absence doesn't mean the activity where teacher accounts for students presence. So the context of sentence is "Miss Janette [...] of students in her class and she notices Brandon is not present today." Can somebody help?

Comment: Related: [Call the roll in the classroom?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/142915/9161), [What verb should I use for a roll call in a classroom? (see example)](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/168144/9161), [The act of calling student names to make list of absent students](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/143533/9161), [What are “class rolls”?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/53148/9161)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways I can think of saying this: *take/call roll* and *take attendance*.

> - [attendance](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/attendance)
>     2a : the persons or number of persons attending something Attendance at the soccer games has been increasing. also : an account of persons attending The teacher took attendance [=made a record of who was present] before starting class.
>     b : the number of times a person attends a student who has perfect attendance [=a student who has been present at every class]
>     (M-W)
> - [call (the) roll and take (the) roll](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/take+roll)
>     to call the names of people from a list of those enrolled, expecting them to reply if they are present. After I call the roll, please open your books to page 12. I will take roll, and then we will do arithmetic.
>     (TFD)

The examples are

> - Miss Janette **takes attendance** of students in her class and she notices Brandon is not present today.
> - Miss Janette **calls roll** of students in her class and she notices Brandon is not present today.

If we previously know that Miss Janette is a teacher, then "of students in her class" becomes optional.

Comment: Ah I see. I'm only familiar absence and presence, although I've heard the word attendance somewhere. But I thought it also has the same meaning as presence. I think I will use the attendance. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The word is *'attendance.'*

Miss Janette ***was taking an attendance*** in her class and she noticed that..

Attendance is an activity where who's present and who's not is marked by a teacher.

I hope this is what you are asking for.

Comment: In Britain we might say "take the register" or do a "roll call".

Comment: Yes, this is the word I'm looking for. I just don't know how to search for it in google. Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelHarvey that is interesting. I never heard a "roll call" before. "Take the register" sounds more familiar in my ear. Thanks!

Comment: Definition of Roll Call : 1 : the act or an instance of calling off a list of names (as for checking attendance) (Merriam-Webster) (Dictionary) [link](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/roll%20call)